# Phonegap + VideoPlayer + Android + local videos not working

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, video-player

I'm creating an app with Phonegap 2.2.0 and I'm trying to play videos locally in my tablet. I'm using MacDonst videoplayer and I'm testing my app in a Galaxy Tab 10.1 with Android 3.1, but I'm no able to see the videos. The links simply don't do any action when I touch them. This is mi html in my assets\www folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/video.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", console.log('ready'), true);
}

function playVideo(vidUrl) {
    window.plugins.videoPlayer.play(vidUrl);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:init()">
    <h1>MacDonst videoplayer</h1>
    <h3>videos</h3>
    <a href="#" onclick="playVideo('file:///android_asset/www/video/comp1_1.mp4')">Play File MP4</a><br><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="playVideo('file:///android_asset/www/video/comp1_1.webm')">Play File WEBm</a><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

I followed the instructions in https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer
And I tried several aproaches found here in stack overflow, but I can't make it work :/

My tablet doesn't have an external sdcard, could that be the problem?
I'm new to Phonegap and Android developing, but I can´t se any erros in LogCat, and I only get 2 warnings:

```
The field Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated VideoPlayer.java
Using MODE_WORLD_READABLE when creating files can be risky, review carefully
```

Can you please help me? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The field Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated" is just a warning. It is not stopping you from playing any video.
all you have to do is-
1. open VideoPlayer.java file in eclipse and press ctrl+shift+o. This will update your plugin.
2. add `<plugin name="VideoPlayer" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer"/>` line in your res/xml/config.xml file.

And done.